# Making an iPhone "senior-friendly"

Tags: iphone-app, accessibility

[image]

I'm looking for something similar to [this Android launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.kunes.android.launcher.demo), but for the iPhone. That is, some solution (not necessarily a "launcher", as perhaps the iPhone doesn't have somehting like that) that would help an elder user to use the very basic functions of an iPhone (making phonecalls, having a very simplified app selection screen, removing distractions, and having accessibility features aimed at lower vision and distraction).

I know you can put the iPhone in "zoomed mode", increase the global font size and activate child mode, but I'm looking into something more similar to the linked Android app. Is there something similar for the iPhone?

Comment: Some basic work with Google seems to indicate that iOS doesn't support alternative launchers (or Apple has not approved any for their " walled garden").

Comment: I have done some basic googling, but my iPhone experience is quite limited, to say the least, hence the question here.

Comment: There is an Apple site of Stackexchange, Ask Different, you can try ask there if no answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS has almost zero support for customizations. What you want is essentially impossible.

You can create Siri shortcuts for them to simplify some common workflows. I doubt it would work all that well, but it's worth a try.

Just buy an Android phone. It's not like Apple cares about niche users.